# object has no attributes. New to classes in python

Tags: python, class

```
import praw
import time

class getPms():

    r = praw.Reddit(user_agent="Test Bot By /u/TheC4T")
    r.login(username='*************', password='***************')

    cache = []
    inboxMessage = []
    file = 'cache.txt'

    def __init__(self):
        cache = self.cacheRead(self, self.file)
        self.bot_run(self)
        self.cacheSave(self, self.file)
        time.sleep(5)
        return self.inboxMessage

    def getPms(self):
        def bot_run():
            inbox = self.r.get_inbox(limit=25)
            print(self.cache)
            # print(r.get_friends())#this works
            for message in inbox:
                if message.id not in self.cache:
                    # print(message.id)
                    print(message.body)
                    # print(message.subject)
                    self.cache.append(message.id)
                    self.inboxMessage.append(message.body)
                    # else:
                    # print("no messages")

        def cacheSave(self, file):
            with open(file, 'w') as f:
                for s in self.cache:
                    f.write(s + '\n')

        def cacheRead(self, file):
            with open(file, 'r') as f:
                cache1 = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f]
            return cache1

        # while True: #threading is needed in order to run this as a loop. Probably gonna do this in the main method though


    # def getInbox(self):
    #     return self.inboxMessage
```

The exception is:

```
  cache = self.cacheRead(self, self.file)
AttributeError: 'getPms' object has no attribute 'cacheRead'
```

I am new to working with classes in python and need help with what I am doing wrong with this if you need any more information I can add some. It worked when it was all functions but now that I attempted to switch it to a class it has stopped working.

Comment: You didn't prefix cache with self. within __init__ which must be done to make it accessible throughout the class. And you have a namespace conflict (__init__ is the constructor, don't name methods with class name in Python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `cacheRead` function (as well as `bot_run` and `cacheSave`) is indented too far, so it's defined in the body of your other function `getPms`. Thus it is only accessible inside of `getPms`. But you're trying to call it from `__init__`.

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve here because `getPms` doesn't have anything else in it but three function definitions. As far as I can tell you should just take out the `def getPms` line and unindent the three functions it contains so they line up with the `__init__` method.

Answer (score 0):

Here are few points:

1. Unless you're explicitly inheriting from some specific class, you can omit parenthesis:

`class A(object):`, `class A():`, `class A:` are equivalent.

2. Your class name and class method have the same name. I'm not sure does Python confuse about this or not, but you probably do. You can name your class `PMS` and your method `get`, for example, so you'll obtain `PMS.get(...)`
3. In the present version of indentation `cacheRead` and `cacheSave` functions are simply inaccessible from init; why not move them to generic class namespace?
4. When calling member functions, you don't need to specify `self` as the first argument since you're already calling the function from this object. So instead of `cache = self.cacheRead(self, self.file)` you have to do it like this: `cache = self.cacheRead(self.file)`

Comment: Under Python versions < 3, `class A(object):` and `class A:` are *not* equivalent. The version that derives from `object` is a new-style class, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867/what-is-the-difference-between-old-style-and-new-style-classes-in-python